# why is my component.render() is in a loop?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am building a simple weather app where I set a place to display the weather forcast with a boolean to control if it will show or not

```
<div className="column">
     {this.state.displayResult ? <WeatherResult /> : null}
</div>
```

There the `displayResult` boolean will set to true by the `handleSubmit()` in the form and the `fetchFavWeather()` on the buttons, and will set to be false by `HandleInputChange()` in the first control class

```
 async getCoord() {

        let city = {
            cityname: this.state.postcodeInput
        }
        axios.post('http://localhost:4001/search-location', city)
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
                this.setState({
                    displayResult: true
                });
            }, (error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }

handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.getCoord();
}

handleInputChange(e) {
        this.setState({
            postcodeInput: e.target.value,
            displayResult: false
        });
}

fetchFavWeather(city){
        
        this.setState({
            displayResult: false,
            postcodeInput: city
        },()=>{
            console.log("passing fav to forcast" + this.state.postcodeInput);
            this.getCoord()
        });
        
    }
fetchFavCities(){

        axios.get('http://localhost:4001/favouriteCites')
        .then((res)=>{
            this.setState({
                favCts: res.data
            })
        });
    }


render() {
    this.fetchFavCities();
    return (
         <div>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <div>
                    <div className="column">
                        {   
                            this.state.favCts.map(
                                    (item, index) => <button key={index} onClick = {() => {this.fetchFavWeather(item)}}>{item}</button>
                        )}
                    </div>
                    <div className="control">
                        <input className="input" type="text" placeholder="input city here" onChange={this.handleInputChange} required />
                    </div>
                    <div className="field">
                        <div className="control">
                            <input type='submit' className="button is-light is-large" value='Check Weather' />
                            <input type='submit' className="button is-light is-large" value='Save as Favourite' onClick = {this.saveAsFavourite}/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <div className="column">
                {this.state.displayResult ? <WeatherResult /> : null}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

however in my WeatherResult Component class, I found out that the render() is being called in an infinite loop, any ideas why?

```
class WeatherResult extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            currentTemp: '',
            humidity: '',
            cityName: '',
            days: []
        }
    }

    async fetchWeather() {
        let response = await fetch('http://localhost:4001/weather');

        await response.json().then(data => {
            console.log(data);
            this.setState({
                currentTemp: data['currentConditions']['temp'] + '°C',
                //humidity: data.main.humidity + '%',
                cityName: data.address,
                days: data.days
            })
        })
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchWeather();
    }

    render() {
        //console.log("why is this looping?");
        return (
            <div>
                <p>Current Conditions at {this.state.cityName}</p>
                <p>Current temperature: {this.state.currentTemp}</p>
                <p>Humidity: {this.state.humidity}</p>
                <p>Location: {this.state.cityName}</p>
                <div>
                    <p>Forcast</p>
                    <p>Date: {this.state.days['datetime']}</p>
                    <p>weatherType: {this.state.days['icon']}</p>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            
        )
    }
}

export default WeatherResult;
```

Comment: Not your issue but why is `days` initialised as an array?

Comment: What drives change to `displayResult` in your parent component?

Comment: I changed it to {} now

Comment: This code should not cause the infinite loop, so the problem should be that one of parent components rerenders. Probably it is related to displayResult state. Can you add jsfiddle example?

Comment: hi @Phil, I have updated the parent class

Comment: hi @Marat, I have updated the parent class

Comment: You haven't added the part where you set / change the `displayResult` state but I'd hazard a guess that you shouldn't be calling `fetchFavCities()` within the `render()` function

Comment: @Phil hi I have updated them all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are called a `fetch` method inside your `render` function which will cause an infinite update loop.

```
render() {
    this.fetchFavCities();
```

Infinite loop will happen because you probably set these favorite cities in your state and reference them here

```
                <div className="column">
                    {   
                        this.state.favCts.map(
                                (item, index) => <button key={index} onClick = {() => {this.fetchFavWeather(item)}}>{item}</button>
                    )}
                </div>
```

Place this outside of `render` function.

Comment: what can I do if I want to get this list of city before render()? I cannot set const in this class either

Comment: why don;t you add it in `componentDidMount` method?